# Dumping postgresql databases and accessing them via ftp

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, tomcat, ftp

I'm developing an automated backup system for a server using PostgreSQL and Tomcat. The environment is CentOS minimal 7. Long story short, a VM will download the .sql dumps and a .tar.gz folder containing Tomcat via FTP.

No problems in setting up vsftpd, I can access the Server via FTP with a custom user (ftpuser) which currently can access a specific folder (/home/ftpuser/backups/). I can compress tomcat there so my script will fetch the backups/ folder and download it, but I cant figure out how to dump the postgresql db to the /home/ftpuser/backups/ folder without having to do some stupid things with sudo.

Postgres user haven't the permission to write there and i can't give them to him even with chown or chmod. I inserted postgres in sudoers and if I dump the db and then I "sudo cp" it to that folder is okay, but in this way I cant use a script to do that, due to "sudo" asking password.

The question is.. Is there a way to enable "pg_dump" to write .sql dump to /home/ftpuser/backups/ folder?

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use FTP for backups. This is how database dumps get leaked. At the absolute least you should be using `rsync` over SSH. It'd also be better to GPG encrypt these before dumping them anywhere.

Comment: that's what they asked me to do, i mean it's sftp obviously, but the question would be the same, how can I pg_dump to a specific folder outside /var/lib/pgsql?

Comment: This is still very risky if password authentication is involved. You want something that's dependent on having a private key, if not even more restricted via VPN, IP whitelisting, or other measures. In any case this is not a programming question. It's probably better directed at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) unless you're working on some kind of script.

Comment: i will post also there, thanks
i will also do GPG before dumping, just to be safer. Unluckily they absolutely want FTP and they pay well for it so i'll try to keep it safer as possible. Like disabling every ip but the backup machine in vsftpd

Comment: The key here is to make sure that several things have to fail in order for there to be a breach, not just one like someone cracking your password. Best of luck trying to keep the client happy *and* secure.

Comment: yep, thanks
btw i'll suggest them to let me use rsync and ssh

Comment: Also instead of sudoers, why not make a `db_backups` type group and add `postgres` plus make that target directory group-writable by that new group?

Comment: i did it, create "backuppers" group and inserted ftpuser and postgres to it, then i did chgrp to set /home/ftpuser/backups/folder writeable to members of the group but when i do pg_dumpall -f /home/ftpuser/backups/try.sql it says permission denied

Comment: You may need to log in again if you've added yourself to a group to get the new permissions applied.

Comment: Ok did it, i had to "sudo chmod g+rw" that folder from postgres.
now i'll delete postgres from sudoers

Comment: But here is another problem! In the server machine ftpuser can read and write /var/backups...when i access through lftp, the "ls" command returns nothing and i cannot even create a folder there

Comment: This is moving heavily into server admin questions, so it's worth shifting this to ServerFault.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

[`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) does not need to be run from the *postgres* user.

Run it from a user that *can* write to the desired folder, and pass the `--username=database_user` parameter to specify the desired database user. You'll probably need a [`.pgpass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) file for the password used by this user (unless it has been defined to be `trust`ed on [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)).

Comment: Oh, didn't know that.
I used another workaround, but I'll keep this in mind. Ty